# Search a Word with space in ES without modifying index mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using spring boot version 2.3.9 Release and ES is 7.6.How to search a Word with space in ES without modifying index mapping.
For Example Name: John Jose
I am trying with below code, but not working. I read some other post that we need to add 'Not analyser'. I no need to modify index mapping. is it possible to add this check in query builder itself.

```
QueryBuilder testQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("cname","John Jose");
```

index mapping

```
"cname": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"ignore_above": 256,
"type": "keyword"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because you are trying [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/query-dsl-match-query.html). By default match query set operator as `OR`.

So for your code, internally it will create query like `John OR Jose` and return result.

If you want both word present in name in any position then you can try to set default operator value `AND` as shown in below. which will create query like `John AND Jose`

```java
QueryBuilder testQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("cname","John Jose").operator(Operator.AND);
```

If you want to do [phrase match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) (execat match) then you can try below query which will internally execute query like `"John Jose"` (as per my understanding you are looking for this query)

```java
QueryBuilder testQuery = QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("cname","John Jose");
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` field is analyzed and by default `standard` analyzer is used, Hence in your case, your `John Jose` will create tokens as `john` and `jose` (notice lowercase as well), and search time also for `match` query it will be tokenize using the same analyzer, So if your indexed documents have content like `John Jose`, it will match.. **No need to do anything from your side.**